# Phonegap Developer App not working

Tags: ios, iphone, node.js, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I want to start developing apps with PhoneGap and for the last two days I've been trying to figure out how to get this to work on my iPhone (5S).

I've followed the steps [here](http://scottbolinger.com/use-phonegap-developer-app/).

First I installed the PhoneGap CLI as said in step 1. I checked the version of the PhoneGap CLI, Cordova and Node.js. It's all correctly installed. I can create an app or open existing apps with the provided commands. But when I do the last step with `$ phonegap serve` (of course I omitted the '$' symbol...). When I execute this command, I get

```
[phonegap] starting app server...
[error] listen EADDRINUSE
```

When I start the app on my pc by going to http://ip-address/ that the PhoneGap Developer App shows on my project, I see a page with a text that says `connecting to device`. After this I open the PhoneGap Developer app on my phone, fill out the ip address and port number and after a few seconds it says `ERROR` -waits a few seconds- `TIMED OUT`.

*Note I opened the terminal window with the `right-click on project folder -> services -> open new terminal window for this folder`, because otherwise I get an error saying `destination folder is not a Cordova project folder` or something similar to this.

So why do I get this `[error] listen EADDRINUSE` error when I run `phonegap serve` and what causes the `ERROR` -waits a few seconds- `TIMED OUT` error?

Comment: Anyone? Does nobody else have this issue?